# C - Most efficient method of filtering an integer array

Tags: c, arrays

I've successfully implemented Eratosthenes' sieve (I know there are faster methods for finding primes, this is just a learning exercise) for prime numbers in C, but I have not found a satisfying way of filtering my returned array of primes for zeros.  To illustrate, when run my program returns this:

$ ./primesieve

Input search limit > 100

0 0 2 3 0 5 0 7 0 0 0 11 0 13 0 0 0 17 0 19 0 0 0 23 0 0 0 0 0 29 0 31 0 0 0 0 0 37 0 0 0 41 0 43 0 0 0 47 0 0 0 0 0 53 0 0 0 0 0 59 0 61 0 0 0 0 0 67 0 0 0 71 0 73 0 0 0 0 0 79 0 0 0 83 0 0 0 0 0 89 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 97 0 0

$

I need some method of filtering the zeros. I'm assuming there is some algorithm more efficient than merely iterating over the return array and copying out the nonzero elements to a second array before printing out the answer, but I haven't been able to find one or come up with one myself.  The integer array is malloc'd on the heap, by the way.

Here's the code.

Edit: Final code pasted in with zero_filter() method implemented.
Edit2: completely forgot the sieve only requires to search up to sqrt(n)... fixed in code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "dbg.h"

void init_array(int sieve[], int size) {

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sieve[i] = i;
    }

    sieve[1] = 0;
}

int prime_filter(int sieve[], int size, int root) {

    int i, j;
    int zero_count = 2;

    for(i = 2; i < root; i++) {
        if(sieve[i] != 0) {
            for(j = 2 * i; j < size; j += i) {
                if(sieve[j] != 0) {
                    sieve[j] = 0;
                    zero_count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return zero_count;
}

void zero_filter(int sieve[], int final_array[], int size) {

    int i;
    int j = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(sieve[i] != 0) {
            final_array[j] = sieve[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
}

void print_array(int final_array[], int size) {

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", final_array[i]);
    }
}

void destroy_arrays(int *sieve, int *final_array) {

    if(sieve) {
        free(sieve);
    }
    if(final_array){
        free(final_array);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    check(argc == 1, "No input required");

    int size, root, rv;  // upper limit on search, return value

    printf("Input search limit > ");
    rv = scanf("%d", &size);
    check(rv != EOF, "Input error on scanf().");
    check(rv != 0, "Input error, expected integer");

    root = (int) sqrt(size) + 1;

    int *sieve, *final_array;
    int zero_count, new_size;

    sieve = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    check(sieve != NULL, "Memory allocation error");

    init_array(sieve, size);
    zero_count = prime_filter(sieve, size, root);

    new_size = size - zero_count;

    final_array = malloc(sizeof(int) * (new_size));
    check(final_array != NULL, "Memory allocation error");

    zero_filter(sieve, final_array, size);
    print_array(final_array, new_size);
    destroy_arrays(sieve, final_array);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;

error:
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: iterating and then seting a qointer to the first non zero item is good enough

Comment: You really don't need to check if `ptr != NULL` before freeing it. `malloc()`ating the sieve is superfluous as well - since you don't return it from any function, you should use an automatic array instead: `int sieve[size]`.

Comment: @H2CO3 I concur unless the ceiling of the sieve is above, say, 100,000, at which time stack-space will become a significant issue (solvable by, among other things, making the sieve global). but you already knew that =P.

Comment: So I should pass the helper functions a pointer to the array on the stack?

Comment: Oh, yes this program will probably be searching above 100,000. Plus, isn't malloc()'ing the array to the heap and passing a pointer to the helper functions far more efficient than passing them the entire array?

Comment: Why do you think there is a faster way to filter out the zeros than to step through the array and copy out the non-zeros?  (If need be you can copy the non-zeros into the "bottom" of your source array, to save the need to allocate a new array, then `realloc` the array to the new size when done.)

Comment: Given this structure, you can't really filter faster than inspecting each element.  But you could combine the filter and print into a single step, and save one pass through the data.

Comment: Actually, there would be a faster way, depending on how large the the zero-blocks in the array are. At first look they seem to get larger the deeper you get. `strlen` (at least in glibc) have a pretty neat way of calculating the length of a string. you may use an inverted strlen to calculate a block of zeroes' length. When you know the length you could just use `memcpy` to copy the non-zero numbers to a new, clean array.

Comment: @Jocke - That makes no sense.  The time it takes to look at a word and see if it's zero is pretty much the same for all schemes, so the only way to gain efficiency is to keep the loop overhead down.  Searching for a "run" would require setup time that just slows you down.  And you'll never, after 3, have adjacent non-zero entries, so doing memcpy is not going to help at all vs simple load/store.

Comment: @DaltonWoodard - Either way you'd just be passing a pointer to the array.  The parameter passing would be essentially identical.  (Not that there's anything wrong with just mallocing.)

Comment: Since it has not been mentioned in comments above explicitly: contrary to @H2CO3 comment above, VLAs should *never* be used when size is determined by user input without known upper bound. And in this case there's no reasonable upper bound, other than  PC RAM+swap space, which can be orders of magnitude more than available stack space. VLAs are cool, but this is a good example of a case where VLA is wrong choice.

Comment: @hyde Not really a "bad choice". There's this concept called "validation of user input".

Comment: @H2CO3 As I explained, in this case (calculating a mathematical series), any reasonable upper limit for input validation is much more than stack size. This is a case where there is no way to use VLA in a safe and sane way (checking available stack space is both OS specific, and imposes an artificially low limit without any justification), it is a wrong choice even with input validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need function like `std::remove` in C++. It "removes" elements in-place. Have a look: [std::remove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove/)
If you not familiar to C++ and templates, here adopted code:

```
int *remove(int *first, int *last, int val)
{
  int *result = first;
  while (first!=last) {
    if (!(*first == val)) {
      *result = *first;
      ++result;
    }
    ++first;
  }
  return result;
}
```

And you can call it with this code:

```
int array[n];
int *end = remove(array, array + n, 0);
size_t not_removed_size = end - array; // values in range [array[0], ... array[not_removed_size]) are non-zeros.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your array in place to compact all the non-zero entries at the front. Something like this, which returns the number of non-zero elements found (off the top of my head - not fully tested, but should illustrate the idea - in particular, `size` should probably be verified to be sane):

```
int compact(int array[], int size)
{ int current = 0, nextpos = 0;

  while (current < size)
  { if (array[current])
    { int tmp = array[nextpos];         // or use a properly defined swap()
      array[nextpos] = array[current];  // but this will be just as fast...
      array[current] = tmp;
      ++nextpos;
    }
    ++current;
  }
  return nextpos;
}
```